# Redirect with status: 401 hangs on "You are being redirected." How do I force redirect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am seeing the following page on unauthorized 401 redirection using rails 4:

[image]

I am fine with this page rendering, but not OK with the page hanging.

The link with anchor text 'redirected' works fine in redirecting to the correct page, but it must be clicked. In other words, the message is incorrect, and I am not being actively redirected.

**How do I force redirect?**

Here is the code that enables this, in [action_controller/metal](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a26a3a075637215c9028308436ca89cba8da2ed5/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting.rb#L61-L68)

```
def redirect_to(options = {}, response_status = {}) #:doc:
  raise ActionControllerError.new("Cannot redirect to nil!") unless options
  raise AbstractController::DoubleRenderError if response_body

  self.status        = _extract_redirect_to_status(options, response_status)
  self.location      = _compute_redirect_to_location(request, options)
  self.response_body = "<html><body>You are being <a href=\"#{ERB::Util.unwrapped_html_escape(location)}\">redirected</a>.</body></html>"
end
```

Comment: Use javascript with a setTimeout

Comment: Good idea, but how do I get the js to run in the layout: false environment just for this view

Comment: You add it to the view itself and use vanilla JS as jquery probably is not loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your view

```
<script>
setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = 'your_url_here' }, 3000);
</script>
```

Or maybe something like this in your controller

```
def redirect_to(options = {}, response_status = {})
  super
  self.response_body = "<html><body><script>setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = \"#{ERB::Util.unwrapped_html_escape(location)}\" }, 3000);</script>You are being <a href=\"#{ERB::Util.unwrapped_html_escape(location)}\">redire‌​cted</a>.</body></ht‌​ml>"
end
```

Comment: There isn't actually a view file anywhere to add this to, and it won't run from assets without a layout.

Comment: self.response_body = "<html><body><script>setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = 'your_url_here' }, 3000);</script>You are being <a href=\"#{ERB::Util.unwrapped_html_escape(location)}\">redirected</a>.</body></html>"  Will this work?

Comment: How do I override this without changing the rails base code

Comment: I deleted my answer about overriding this in the application controller.. it seems to break redirecting somehow.